# What is the URL to a Visualforce page without Sites

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I have created a Visualforce page:

**CustomVisuaforce.page**

```
<apex:page>
    <h1>Custom Visualforce Page</h1>
</apex:page>
```

I want to access to page from within Salesforce without using Sites.

The current user is System Administrator so the Visualforce page is automatically added to the profile.

I have tried these URLs:

- `https://orgname--sandboxname.my.salesforce.com/CustomVisuaforce`
- `https://orgname--sandboxname.my.salesforce.com/lightning/CustomVisuaforce`
- `https://orgname--sandboxname.my.salesforce.com/lightning/n/CustomVisuaforce`

But I am not able to view the Visualforce page.

**Question**

1. What URL do I use to access this page from within Salesforce Lightning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `/apex/CustomVisuaforce`. In Classic, it will go to the page, and in Lightning, it will redirect to the correct URL for you.